# Как создать гейм инвайт на Facebook

Tags: facebook

Господа, ситуация такова - есть игра в Аппстор которую я хотел бы рекомендовать или скорее пригласить играть своих Фейсбук друзей. Скажите пожалуйста, этот функционал должен быть как то изначально вписан в код игры? Или это можно сделать средствами самого ФБ?

Если этот гейм инвайт надо прописывать в коде самого аппликейшена - насколько сложно это будет сделать челу не разбирающемуся в кодинге? Буду благодарен всем советам!